# Compare different columns of two files with different field separators while second file has unequal number of columns

Tags: awk

I want to compare second column of file1 with the last column of file2 (species name) and if they match print first column of file1 and all columns of file2 as a result. However those files contain different field separators and the second file have unequal number of columns when `__` is used as separator. Both files contain only unique lines.
I have tried to solve this problem with grep and partial line match however it seems that awk is more suitable for this.

file1:

```
AF074611.1  Yersinia pestis 
AE002160.2  Chlamydia muridarum 
AE002162.1  Chlamydia muridarum 
AE003849.1  Xylella fastidiosa
```

file2:

```
o__Enterobacterales;f__Yersiniaceae;g__Yersinia;s__Yersinia pestis
o__Enterobacterales;f__Yersiniaceae;g__Yersinia;s__
o__Methylococcales;f__Crenotrichaceae;g__Crenothrix;s__Crenothrix polyspora
o__Methylococcales;f__;g__;s__
o__Xanthomonadales;f__Xanthomonadaceae;g__Xylella;s__
o__Xanthomonadales;f__Xanthomonadaceae;g__Xylella;s__Xylella fastidiosa
o__Xanthomonadales;f__Xanthomonadaceae;g__Xylella;s__Xylella taiwanensis
```

output:

```
AF074611.1  o__Enterobacterales;f__Yersiniaceae;g__Yersinia;s__Yersinia pestis
AE003849.1  o__Xanthomonadales;f__Xanthomonadaceae;g__Xylella;s__Xylella fastidiosa
```

How I could achive this? Thanks.

Comment: You said `Both files contain only unique lines` but file1 at least doesn't only contain unique **key values** (e.g. `Chlamydia muridarum`) - if file2 does not only contain unique key values then add a second line with key value `Yersinia pestis` to file2. Either way add a 2nd line with key value `Yersinia pestis` to file1 so we can see what the output looks like with matching duplicate key values in applicable files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what I expect you'd want if there are matching duplicate key values in either or both files:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR  { a[$2][$1]; next }
    $NF in a { for (val in a[$NF]) print val, $0 }
' FS='\t' file1 FS='__' file2
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file1
AF074611.1      Yersinia pestis
AE002160.2      Chlamydia muridarum
AE002162.1      Chlamydia muridarum
AE003849.1      Xylella fastidiosa
added_value     Yersinia pestis

$ cat file2
o__Enterobacterales;f__Yersiniaceae;g__Yersinia;s__Yersinia pestis
o__Enterobacterales;f__Yersiniaceae;g__Yersinia;s__
o__Methylococcales;f__Crenotrichaceae;g__Crenothrix;s__Crenothrix polyspora
o__Methylococcales;f__;g__;s__
o__Xanthomonadales;f__Xanthomonadaceae;g__Xylella;s__
o__Xanthomonadales;f__Xanthomonadaceae;g__Xylella;s__Xylella fastidiosa
o__Xanthomonadales;f__Xanthomonadaceae;g__Xylella;s__Xylella taiwanensis
o__added_here_too;f__Yersiniaceae;g__Yersinia;s__Yersinia pestis

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2][$1];next} $NF in a{for (val in a[$NF]) print val, $0}' FS='\t' file1 FS='__' file2
AF074611.1 o__Enterobacterales;f__Yersiniaceae;g__Yersinia;s__Yersinia pestis
added_value o__Enterobacterales;f__Yersiniaceae;g__Yersinia;s__Yersinia pestis
AE003849.1 o__Xanthomonadales;f__Xanthomonadaceae;g__Xylella;s__Xylella fastidiosa
AF074611.1 o__added_here_too;f__Yersiniaceae;g__Yersinia;s__Yersinia pestis
added_value o__added_here_too;f__Yersiniaceae;g__Yersinia;s__Yersinia pestis
```

The above uses GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays, it's an easy tweak to make it work for any awk if you don't have gawk.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next} $5 in a {print a[$5],$0}' FS='\t' file1 FS='__' file2
```

In this script, `file1` is read first and its fields are recorded in an array `a`. Then the second file is processed with a different field separator.

Comment: Corrected, thank you. Indeed, bashisms should be avoided.